# Putting data from .csv files in an array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with 57 .csv files. I want to read them in one Variable (called FOS). So FOS must be an array. But how to load these .csv files in an array with Pandas? In addition, there are some missing files...

I tried to make a for-loop and wanted to put every file on a particular place of the array. Like File_1.csv ist on FOS[0] and File_57 on FOS[57].

```
FOS=[]
for i in range(1,57):        
    if i != 5:      # Because Filename_5 is missing in the dataset...
        FOL[i]=pd.read_csv("Path\Filename{0}.csv".format(i), some more parameters like name)
```

But now I get the Error: "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"

Comment: can you please share some more code. What data do you want in `FOS` (a dict?)

Comment: kindly show sample data of csv

Comment: Sure. It's a dataset of some sensor data, but I couldn't post a Screen in the comments. So I had to post an answer

Comment: Are you sure, you don't want to concat the data into one common dataframe with the records of all files? btw your index out of range is because you created a list of size 0 (no elements) and you can't grow the list by assigning an object to a slot of it. You could have avoided that by initializing FOS to `FOS=[None] * 57` but thats not quite pythonic I think. Usually this is done by using `FOS.append(pd....)` in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something short like:

```
import os

FOS=[pd.read_csv(f"Path/Filename{i}.csv")
        for i in range(1,57)
            if os.path.exists(f"Path/Filename{i}.csv")
]
```

Explanation:
This uses a list comprehension. That means the expression `[....]` constructs the list. It is equivalent to wrting:

```
EOS= list()
for i in range(1,57):
    if os.path.exists(f"Path/Filename{i}.csv"):
        EOS.append(pd.read_csv(f"Path/Filename{i}.csv"))
```

The `if os.path.exists(f"Path/Filename{i}.csv")` is just more dynamic as to exclude file 5. In case you do this more often and your input files vary it is more convenient. But maybe in that case you should rather read a file list (e.g. by using `os.listdir`).

Answer (score 0):

You can take it a bit more dynamic. first move all files that need to be read into a single directory. Now use `os module` to traverse through and fetch all file paths in case you have sub directories.

```
import os

import pandas as pd


def _fetch_file_locations(root_path: str, extension: str) -> iter:
    """
    This function reads all files of a particular extension. It traverses 
    through sub directories and finds all files 
    :param root_path: the path from where it needs to start looking for files
    :param extension: the extension of the file that it's looking for
    :return: the array of file paths of all the files that were found
    """
    if not os.path.isdir(root_path):
        raise NotADirectoryError(f'There is no directory at path: {root_path}')

    file_collection = []

    file_collection += [os.path.join(root, file) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path)
                        for file in files if extension in file]

    return file_collection


def main(root_path: str):
    all_files = _fetch_file_locations(root_path, extension='.csv')

    # uses pandas to read all he CSV files and convert the dataframe to an array of dictionary
    file_contents = [pd.read_csv(file_path).to_dict('record') for file_path in all_files]

    # converts the array of arrays into a single array of dicts
    all_contents_in_one = [record for content in file_contents for record in content]

    print(f"Found {len(all_contents_in_one)} records after merging {len(all_files)}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(r'X:\worky')
```

Comment: Could be right, but didn't test it. Also very fast and nice explanation.